# ajax like/unlike post in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

Ive been working to implement a like/unlike feature which works with ajax. I have already built and tested the models and associations which seem to working fine. What I am having problems with is rendering the actual like/unlike button in the view. I have been using this https://github.com/Aufree/ting/tree/master/app/controllers github projects like/unlike system as reference for building my own.

Heres my controller likeships_controller.rb

```
before_action :authenticate_user!

include LikeshipsHelper
def create
  current_user.like!(params[:likeable_type], params[:likeable_id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to correct_path }
    format.js
  end
end

def destroy
  current_user.unlike!(params[:likeable_type], params[:likeable_id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to correct_path }
    format.js
  end
end
```

Heres my likeship_helper.rb

```
  module LikeshipsHelper
    def likeable_likes_tag like
      @count = Likeship.where("likeable_type = ? and likeable_id = ?", like[:likeable_type], like[:likeable_id]).count
      if @count > 0
        likes_count = @count
      else
        likes_count = ''
      end

      if current_user && current_user.liking?(like)
        link_title = "unlike"
        link_path_method = "delete"
       fa_icon = '<i class="red heart icon"></i>'
      else
        link_title = "like"
        link_path_method = "post"
       fa_icon = '<i class="red heart empty icon"></i>'
      end

      if current_user.blank?
        "#{likes_count}#{fa_icon}".html_safe 
      else
        link_to "#{likes_count}#{fa_icon}".html_safe, 
                                                          likeships_path(like), 
                                                          title: link_title, 
                                                          class: "animated zoomIn",
                                                          method: link_path_method, 
                                                          remote: true
        end

    end

    def correct_path
      if params[:likeable_type].to_s == "Post"
        post_path(params[:likeable_id])
      end
    end
  end
```

these are my views

_like.html.erb

```
    <i class="red heart icon">
    <%= form_for(current_user.likeships.build) do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :likeable_type, value: @likeable[:likeable_type] %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :likeable_id, value: @likeable[:likeable_id] %>
      <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
    </i>
```

_likes.html.erb

```
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
      <% if current_user.liking?(@likeable) %>
        <%= render 'likeships/unlike' %>
      <% else %>
        <%= render 'likeships/like' %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

**EDIT:** Now if i use this in the _post.html.erb view no error is thrown but no like/unlike button appears either.

```
<div class="post_wrapper">
<div class="media_wrapper">

    <span class="name"><%= link_to post.user.name, post.user, class: "name" %></span>           
    <p class="media"><%= post.body_html %></p>
    <div class="date_and_like">

            <span class="item" id="like-post-#{@post.id}" >
                <% @likeable = Likeship.likeable(@post) %>
                <%= likeable_likes_tag @likeable %>
            </span>

        <span class="timestamp"><%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago </span>

    </div>
</div>
```

heres the create.js.erb file

```
$("#like-post-<%= params[:likeable_id] %>").html("<%= j(likeable_likes_tag @likeable) %>")
```

So I also tried to render the likes form in the post view with this

but it gave me an error that

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Ive been stumped for hours trying to figure this out any help would be awesome, also let me know if you need any additional info, Thanks.

Comment: Knowing exactly which line generated that nil error would be a big help.

Comment: sorry about that, here you go.  <%= f.hidden_field :likeable_type, value: @likeable[:likeable_type] %> from the like partial

Comment: The error is probably because @likeable is not set or in scope at the time.   I'm still not sure about the order of where everything is loaded.   What surrounds the `likeable_likes_tag @likeable` section? is any of that getting rendered?